# Rental Property 1031 Exchange & Boot

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, like-kind-exchange

Is a mortgage **"boot"** still considered a recognized gain even if the debt, LTV (loan to value) and purchase price have all increased or remained the same in the exchange?

*Note: If you aren't familiar with the term "boot" see example below.*

The question may appear simple, but even the most simple example is still complicated. Here is an example that is very close to real life:

1. Purchase a property for $165,000 ($132,000 debt/loan) - 80% LTV
2. 4 years later: 1031 Exchange
   Sell original property for $280,000 -/minus approx 3% in fees = $271,000
   Remaining Mortgage $123,000
   Net Proceeds are: $148,000
3. Purchase Exchange property for $280,000 ($224,000 debt/loan) - 80% LTV
   Down Payment is $56,000
   Net Proceeds (boot) after down payment: $92,000

To repeat the question for the example: **is the $92,000 "boot"** considered a recognized gain and taxable? ie. would it need to be part of the down-payment (thus a final loan of $132k just like the original loan) in order to be safe from capitol gains tax? What if the purchase price was even greater, yet there was still a boot? ie. is boot always considered a recognized gain?

Comment: Was this a primary residence, rental, vacation, or investment property?

Comment: @BenVoigt Long term rental, investment property. It has never been my residence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://finance.zacks.com/transfer-capital-gains-new-property-8920.html

> You can use Section 1031 to transfer all capital gains to a new property if the exchange is pure and money does not change hands. Or, you can transfer a portion of capital gains to new property if, in addition to an exchange of property, you also receive a sum of money. In this case **you will need to pay tax on the money you receive**.

The $92k of equity that you withdrew will be taxed.  Since your capital gain was ($271k-$165k) = $106k, the exchange has deferred (but not eliminated) an unrealized gain in the amount of ($106k - $92k) = $14k -- your basis in the new property will be only $266k.